# What is the meaning of Will words after investigating the murder scene?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Will say this words to board meeting members about his investigation about Serial Killer's murder case.

> Will: Skillful entry indicates premeditation and planning. Therefore, I
>   believe he's an organized individual who probably lives life
>   competently with little or no leakage.
>
> Board member: Meaning in appearance he could be absolutely anyone?
>
> Will: That's right.
>
> Will: Bodies being arranged into an audience and **the mirrors make me believe
>    that there's a rich and intense fantasy life going on here**. The
>    elevated experience is the fantasy. The act fuels the fantasy. The act fuels the fantasy.To discover what he thinks he's doing in there,
>   why he picked who he picked, did what he did, to understand his motive,
>   you have to know his illusions, his dreams.
>
> Board member: Which are?
>
> Will: I don't know.

How Mirror & fantasy are related to each other, I really don't know why he is referring to mirror with fantasy in his statement?

Comment: The context of this is very confusing. If I were to hazard a (random) guess, it would be that what you see in the mirror is not the real world, but a backwards representation of it...

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Who is "Will"? Without the context of the quotation, we can only guess at its meaning. Please **[edit]** your question to include the source, Without more information, the question may be closed. Please read our [**tour**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages, and also our [**Details, Please**](https://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post. They will help you to write a better question.

Comment: I added details, is it enough to answer my question?

Comment: We still don't know where the mirrors came from. We need to know the context. What is going on in the story? What audience is he talking about? Why are there bodies lying about? Can you add a link to the source?

Comment: Have you looked up the meaning of "fantasy"? What did you find?

Comment: @NathanTuggy This is evidently a filmscript, but Google returns no trace of it...

Comment: Eureka! This is from the film _Manhunter (1986),_ and "Will" is the character Will Graham.

Comment: I added even more details, still not enough to answer my question?

Comment: The killer arranges the bodies and mirrors to create a _fantasy._ As @NathanTuggy advised, use your dictionary to learn about that word. You might also try to watch the 1986 film _Manhunter,_ from which this dialogue is taken. This is a question about interpretation, though, and I'm afraid it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more important phrase is

> bodies being arranged into an audience

What Will is talking about is how a psychopath lives *in their own world* and the murderer is trying to recreate part of that world in the *display* left at the scene of the crime.

The **mirrors**, as well as the bodies, may be thought of **props** on a *stage set* left by the murderer.  Obviously the mirrors have been *purposefully* placed.